# Mongoose populated() returns undefined despite the path being populated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the following Mongoose schemas:

```js
// server/models/Order.js

const { connection, model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = new Schema({
    product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    purchasePrice: {
        type: Schema.Types.Decimal128, get: Number, required: true, validate: {
            validator: function (value) {
                return !this.populated('product') || +value === this.product.price;
            },
        }
    },
});

const schema = new Schema({
    // ...
    items: [itemSchema],
    // ...
});

module.exports = model('Order', schema);
```

My server creates a new Order, populates it and then attempts to save it:

```js
// server/routers/order.js

const Order = require('../models/Order');

const order = new Order({ ... });
await order.populate('items.product').execPopulate();
const { _id } = await order.save();
```

which invokes the validation function. The debugger shows that `this.product` refers to a valid document,   and yet `this.populated('product')` returns `undefined`, so the comparison `+value === this.product.price` is not evaluated.

Is this a bug in Mongoose or is this how it's supposed to behave for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it's a bug.
I found this too.

```
const trackSchema=new Schema({
  song:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"Attachments",
   index:true
  },
  played:{
   type:Number,
   default:0
  }
});
const playlistSchema=const plSchema=new Schema({
  name:String,
  tracks:[trackSchema]
});
```

Before populate:

```
playlist.tracks.forEach((track)=>{
   console.log('track.song: ',track.song);
   //this prints ObjectId
});
```

After populate:

```
await playlist.populate('tracks.song').execPopulate();
playlist.tracks.forEach((track)=>{
   console.log('track.song: ',track.song);
   //this prints undefined
});
```

Modified to this:

```
await playlist.populate('tracks').execPopulate();
playlist.tracks.forEach((track)=>{
   console.log('track.song: ',track.song);
   //this prints undefined
});
```

Still undefined ‍♂️